# React Router v5 - Global No match in Nested Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have two route 'stacks' in my React app:

- Public (Login, Register, 404, etc - /login, /register)
- Private (Dashboard - /app/*)

When user is logged, Dashboard routes stack is used where is next nested router to match sub pages.
When route does not exist I want to show global No Match (404) route from 'Public' stack, but when I have this at the end of router, empty Dashboard route is shown, not the last in setup:

App.tsx

```js
return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
          <Route path="/app/*" render={(props) => (isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />)} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
```

Dashboard.tsx

```js
export default function Dashboard(props: RouteComponentProps): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome} exact />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateContent} />
        <Route path="/manage" component={ManageContent} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So when I for example access `/foobar` I see content of component `Dashboard` without any other content.

I tried to make a redirect at the end of Dashboard, but this does not seems ok to me by design:

```js
// End of Dashboard Switch
<Route render={() => <Redirect to="/404" />} />

// Changed NotFound route
<Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation (https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components/route-matchers):

> When a  is rendered, it searches through its children  elements to find one whose path matches the current URL. When it finds one, it renders that  and ignores all others.

Using Redirect block helps to solve the problem in this case. Add it to your Dashboard component:

```
export default function Dashboard(props: RouteComponentProps): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome} exact />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateContent} />
        <Route path="/manage" component={ManageContent} />
        <Route><Redirect to="/404" /></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did this. Is this the only way to do it? :D

Comment: Seems, this is the only way. If a control flow goes by some route, it will never choose another one without redirect. A proof link: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components/route-matchers

Comment: when page is reloaded, even all the routes get redirected to 404